# How to add desktop shortcut for URL, ignoring web app manifest?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, chrome-for-android, home-screen-shortcuts, samsung-galaxy-s7

**Goal:**  Have a desktop shortcut that opens https://news.google.com/news/i#0 , ignoring the contained web app manifest that otherwise "overrides" the saved shortcut to http://news.google.com/news?sapa=1 and with `"display": "standalone"`.

I had this working previously on an older Android phone before a replacement / upgrade.

Prior to the upgrade, I was able to long-press and open individual articles in new tabs - as well as copy link shortcuts to specific articles, as well as all of the other features and functionality that Chrome has to offer.  Here is just a partial selection of references of other users complaining about the same:

- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/news/MdZ22eC1X1Y
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/news/bLlTM_OhTns

Using https://news.google.com/news/i#0 provides a temporary successful work-around.  However, I can't find a successful way to add a link for this to my home screen.  The "Add to Home screen" option within Chrome instead saves a link to http://news.google.com/news?sapa=1 - and in such a way that it opens as a web application instead of a web page within Chrome:

- https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest

On a desktop operating system, this would be a non-issue.  (Create shortcut, enter desired URL, done.)

## Attempt 1: Provide my own Manifest

So I created my own manifest - editing https://news.google.com/news/ui/resources/json/manifest.json to change the `start_url` attribute to `https://news.google.com/news/i#0`, and the `display` attribute from `standalone` to `browser`.  I then created my own HTML page that simply contained the below - then self-hosted both on a local web server:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <Title>Google News</Title>
                <link rel="manifest" href="/news/manifest.json"/>
        </head>
        <body>
                Test
        </body>
</html>
```

However, this doesn't work:  Despite the shortcut being saved with the desired name and icon, it links back to my self-hosted HTML page, and not the indicated `start_url`.  Unfortunately, it appears that cross-domain URLs are not allowed per the manifest intent - as per https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/183 and https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/196 .

### Attempt 1b: MITM website

Within the confines of my own local network, I figured I could try to [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) (MITM) the website to temporarily provide a desired manfiest to use for addition to the home screen.  Unfortunately, the website uses [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) here, which appropriately blocks the attempt.

Regardless - this is way too much work for what should be a simple effort.

## Attempt 2: Widget Bookmark

Unfortunately, it looks like the 1x1 bookmark widget was removed in Chrome 48, as per https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Ikn2YhvT98s .  The suggested work-around is to use the "Add to Home screen" feature within Chrome.  Goto 10 / see beginning.

## Attempt 3: Use the default-provided "Internet" browser

Unfortunately, using "Add shortcut on Home screen" in the default-provided "Internet" browser produces the same result as Chrome.

## Consideration 4: Use a custom app / widget

Could probably write and install a custom application or widget that could be added to the home screen to meet the goal.

Or don't re-invent the wheel, and use an existing one.  Some possibilities:

- "More Shortcuts": https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.moreshortcuts&hl=en
- "Shortcut Customizer": https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dezits.shortcut4file&hl=en

## Conclusion

How can someone create a desktop shortcut to an arbitrary URL, ignoring a provided web app manifest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## To bypass any site's web app manifest

1. Copy the following code

   ```
   JavaScriptx:<!-- NOTE: JavaScriptx is NOT A TYPO!!! -->
   if (meta=document.querySelector('meta[name="mobile-web-app-capable"]')) meta.parentNode.removeChild(meta);
   if (mani=document.querySelector('link[rel="manifest"]')) mani.parentNode.removeChild(mani);
   void(0)
   ```
2. Open Chrome on Android
3. Go to the URL you want to add to your Home screen, for example:

   - https://news.google.com/news/i#0
4. Paste the code copied earlier into Chrome's Location bar
5. Scroll to the beginning of the pasted code

   - (Touch & Drag repeatedly on the text in the Location bar to scroll it
6. Touch after the `x` in `JavaScriptx`
7. Backspace the `x`, using whatever your <kbd>Backspace</kbd> button looks like on the on-screen keyboard
8. Touch <kbd>Go</kbd> on the on-screen keyboard (to confirm/accept the URL & run it)

The JavaScript should execute on the page & it should appear to do nothing, that's fine.

Note: if the page reloads for *any reason*, you'll need to run the JavaScript again.

Now, try adding that page to the Home screen again.

## To add the URL to the Home screen

9. Touch Chrome's on-screen "3 dots menu" (on the right of the Location bar, next to the "open tab count" button) or use the hardware menu button
10. Touch **Add to Home screen**

It should end up as a normal Chrome link, not as a Web App, since the JavaScript nuked the page's preference for "web app mode".

## Questions / Comments?

#### Why did you have me copy `JavaScriptx` just to have me backspace the x off later?

Because, in my testing, on my phone, when I pasted anything with `JavaScript:` at the beginning, Chrome ripped that part off, leaving only the text after it.