# Chrome bookmark on home screen to BBC News opens as webapp

Tags: chrome-for-android, home-screen-shortcuts

Using my Samsung Galaxy Tab3 10.1 (4.4.2) I have just started using Chrome as the default browser instead of the built in "Internet".

I have recreated many of the bookmark links on the home screen without issue, and they open Chrome as expected.

However if I open http://www.bbc.co.uk/news and then "Add to Home Screen", the bookmark opens Chrome as a webapp meanng there are no tabs or any ability to use it like a normal browser.

How on earth can I stop it opening as a webapp, and make it open as a normal tab?

Comment: Thanks @beeshyams, but the blog shows the `<meta>` tag from the site itself... which I obviously have no control over.

Comment: @beeshyams, it means that the BBC website developers are the only ones who can change the instruction. But you *have* helped,  as it is has shown that it's simple not possible for me to override it,  which is highly frustrating (at least not that I've found)

Comment: I've just [found this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/156135/41980) which has worked perfectly :-)