# How to "Add to Home screen" a shorcut with a dynamic URL?

Tags: chrome-for-android, home-screen-shortcuts, bookmarks, javascript

I have a Google Form that I use for daily tracking and I would like to have a shortcut to this form on my home screen.

One field of this form is for the date and I would like to have it pre-filled with today's date. To do so, I can pass a query string to the URL, that will end up looking like:

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<formId>/viewform?entry.<fieldId>=YYYY-MM-DD
```

Since today's date is not the same as tomorrow's (yay!), this URL needs to be updated every day with a different `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I followed this post and has been able to create a bookmark with a dynamic URL using JavaScript, on Chrome Desktop: [How to create a dynamic bookmark with today’s date in the URL](https://trendblog.net/how-to-create-a-dynamic-bookmark-with-todays-date-in-the-url/), but I would also like to have it on my phone.

I came across [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/156135/269083), where it shows how to use JavaScript to change the current page. However, when applied to my case, it will compute the date before creating the URL, so this URL is not dynamic.

Is there a *"native"* way to achieve this? My other option for the moment would be having a local HTML page that redirects to the form.